# Check if Time of DateTimeField is > 18:00 Clock

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm writing a admin panel in that we need to check if the action was performed in after hours at work and I need to determine if

```
 date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

is over 18:00 / 06:00 PM and display it in the Admin View, if it's true.

How can I compare a DateTimeField if it's time is > 18:00 per Day?

Update:

This works for me

```
def On_Call_duty(self):
    if (self.date.hour+2) >= 17:
        return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:orange; padding: 5px;">Yes</div>'
    else:
        return '<div style="width:100%%; height:100%%; background-color:limegreen; padding: 5px; ">No</div>'
On_Call_duty.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Django 1.6? If so [__hour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#hour)

Comment: You could write custom method which does `return self.date.hour > 18`